# How to do "diff" to two trees saved in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I need to save a 3-level tree structure into MySQL. Before each time I modified the tree, I will copy the original tree somewhere.After modification, I need to know the "diff" result of my modification.

For example, the original tree is:

```
.
├── GroupA
│   ├── NodeA
│   │   └── LeafA
│   └── NodesB
└── GroupB
```

After my modification, the new tree is:

```
.
├── GroupA
│   ├── NodeB
│   ├── NodeA
│   │   ├── LeafA
│   │   └── LeafB
│   └── NodesB
└── GroupB
```

I need to know:

- There's one more leaf under GroupA->NodeA
- There's one more branch under GroupA

And so on.

So what's the best way to store this tree so I can get "diff" result between modifications?

Here's my solution:

1. Since this tree is a three-level tree, I store the tree using 3 tables. When I need to retrieve the whole tree, simply join each table.
2. Before any modification, I'll dump the 3 main tables into 3 temporary tables.
3. After any modification, I can retrieve two trees from the 3 main tables and the 3 temporary tables, then "diff" them without any SQL operation.

I tried to log modifications, but a simple operation log cannot handle situations like this:

- Add leafA
- Delete leafA
- Add leafA

There will be 3 logs but actually there's only one modification

So, is there any better solution? Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: First, you should in future tree-implementations consider 1 table instead of one per level, as this would scale much more easily than having one table per level. With just one table you could support an unspecified number of levels.

Comment: As for your diff, the problem here is that there's a ton of operations you have said nothing about, so it depends on how advanced you want the diff to be. For instance, can you move nodes? What if you moved NodeA under GroupB, can you do that? What should your diff tell you then? That you removed something under GroupA and inserted something else under GroupB, or should it be smart enough to actually say "You moved this from here to there"? ie. do you want to list that as two independent operations, or just one?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen♦ For you example( _Move NodeA from GroupA to GroupB_ ), I need to regard it as two independent operation. So the diff result should tell me "**NodeA is deleted from GroupA**" and "**one node named NodeA is added to GroupB**".

Comment: You mention "mysql", does your solution have to be built in SQL or do you use an external programming language for it?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen♦ Currently I use PHP to generate two temporary files containing the old tree and new tree from MySQL, then simply diff the two temporary files. This, IMO, is inefficient when the tree is really large

Answer (score 0):

I bet you should flat you tree data and then make is easier?
for instance:

add a code field in your table

```
├── GroupA(xxxa_1)
│   ├── NodeA(xxxa_1_1)
│   │   └── LeafA(xxxa_1_1_1)
│   └── NodesB(xxxa_1_1)


├── GroupA(xxxb_1)
│   ├── NodeB(xxxb_1_1)
│   ├── NodeA(xxxb_1_1)
│   │   ├── LeafA(xxxb_1_1_1)
│   │   └── LeafB(xxxb_1_1_1)
│   └── NodesB(xxxb_1_1)
```

xxxa and xxxb are the first node'id